# Get the value of an element whose id changes

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the values of multiple inputs on a page. The ids of the inputs are generated dynamically.

```
<input id="updates_662224305" class="text quantity" type="text" value="1" name="updates[662224305]" size="4">
```

I am running a loop for the table and cells in which the inputs are contained. I was getting the innerHTML of the cells the inputs are located in, and then slicing the section where their ids are:

```
var racetamarray = [],
racetamtotal = 0,
table = document.getElementById('cart-table'),
cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td');

for (var i=0,len=cells.length; i<len; i++){

    if(cells[i].innerHTML.indexOf("ncombo-racetam") != -1) {
        i+=3;
        var racetaminput = cells[i].innerHTML;
        var racetaminputcontain = racetaminput.slice(43,60);
        var racetamelem = document.getElementById(racetaminputid);
        racetamarray.push(parseInt(racetamelem.value));
    }
}
```

This worked in firefox, as I was able to extract their ids and put them in the variable `racetamelem`. However when I tried it in chrome it does not work, the slice occurs at a different section of the string and does not capture their ids. Is there a better way to slice this or of converting the inputs from a string to a DOM element?

HTML of one of the rows in the table:

```
<tr class="item sampler-pramiracetam-capsules">
<td>
<span class="ncombo-racetam"></span>
<a href="/products/sampler-pramiracetam-capsules">
<img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0173/1766/products/PramiracetamCaps_grande_thumb.jpg?v=1396441752"  alt="Sampler, Pramiracetam Capsules" />
</a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="/products/sampler-pramiracetam-capsules">Sampler, Pramiracetam Capsules - 30 Capsules</a></td>
<td>$8.90</td>
<td><input class="text quantity" type="text" size="4" id="updates_658967781" name="updates[658967781]" value="1" class="replace"  /></td>
<td>$8.90</td>
<td><a class="btn remove-from-cart" href="/cart/change?id=658967781&quantity=0">Remove</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Any chance you could put this in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Why don't you just do `inputs = table.getElementsByTagName('input')` to get all inputs into a NodeList?

Comment: Agree with MrCode. Depending on browser support requirements, you could also use `table.querySelectorAll('input')`

Comment: There are any number of inputs on the page. I only want to get the values of those that have a tag with the class "ncombo-racetam" two cells to their left in the same row of the table. I'm not sure how that would work comparing all of the inputs to what's in two cells over.

Comment: Can you show the HTML for one of the rows that includes the `ncombo-racetam` element?

Comment: Updated with the HTML of a row.

Comment: I don't see `ncombo-racetam` only `ncombo-choline` which is 3 cells left.

Comment: Sorry I pasted the wrong row, it's correct now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This walks through the table rows and checks for any elements in the first cell with the class name, and if found then push the input value (from the fourth cell) to the array.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SEaE4/

```
var racetamarray = [];
var table = document.getElementById('cart-table');
var row;

for(var i=0; i<table.rows.length; i++){
    row = table.rows[i];
    if(row.cells.length > 3){
        if(row.cells[0].querySelectorAll('.ncombo-racetam').length) {
            racetamarray.push(row.cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value);
        }
    }
}

console.log(racetamarray);
```

Side note: if you need to support IE7 or older then you will need to replace the `querySelectorAll()` call with more code to check each element for the class.